# Same cshtml view in different style display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Same cshtml view in different style display.
ie. I want to make visible some elements in the view when redirect from one link and from other link click hide some other elements.

I have a cshtml of **ItemMaster**. I need to display same view for Food items and Drug items. For food items display, i want to hide some elements regarding Drugs.

Comment: Either create separate views or pass a parameter to the method that can be used to conditionally determine what elements should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In your model object, have one or more boolean property. Control visibility of HTML element using model property. The controller will set the visibility properties of model and send the model to the view. Same view will be used with different model object to render different UI.

Comment: I normally prefer to include an example however in this case its bit of work. I may still find time to cook up something for you tomorrow. Meanwhile why don't you start with a simple example and share the basic code. People would love to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create different actions for the controller and redirect the same view,
within the view get the action names and show what contents you want to show and hide respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you should not show those drug items. It can be done by the following ways:

```
@Html.Hidden(m=>m.DrugItem1)
```

Or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DrugItem1, new {type="hidden"});
```